# 32feet gives me an exception if I send and receive at the same time

Tags: android, .net, bluetooth, 32feet

Im using 32feet to connect to an android phone with bluetooth. Both the phone and the pc have a bluetooth (bt) client and a server running. Everything works fine if I do only a send or a receive, but if I do a send on **both** sides at the same time, on the pc I get an exception.

In other words, this is what needs to happen simultaneously for me to get an exception.

```
BT Client PC * -------> BT Server Android (pc client gets exception)
BT Server PC   <------- BT Client Android (everything is fine every time (message is received))

(*)  Exception, android doesn't see the connection attempt
```

This is the exception:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An invalid argument was supplie
d 083D88459AE0:1c556c4d4d9a422691cfff53d3634cd3
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddre
ss socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at InTheHand.Net.Bluetooth.Msft.SocketBluetoothClient.Connect(BluetoothEndPoi
nt remoteEP)
   at InTheHand.Net.Sockets.BluetoothClient.Connect(BluetoothEndPoint remoteEP)
   at BluetoothClientTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\gyozo\testprojects\B
luetoothClient\BluetoothClient\Program.cs:line 37
```

I don't know what is wrong. Any help is appreciated.